# Flask celery tasks not working

Tags: python, configuration, flask, celery, celery-task

I configured my project, referring to this answer:
[How to use Flask-SQLAlchemy in a Celery task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12044776/how-to-use-flask-sqlalchemy-in-a-celery-task)

My `extension.py` file:

```
import flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from config import BaseConfig
from celery import Celery
from flask_mail import Mail
from celery.schedules import crontab


class FlaskCelery(Celery):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(FlaskCelery, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.patch_task()

        if 'app' in kwargs:
            self.init_app(kwargs['app'])

    def patch_task(self):
        TaskBase = self.Task
        _celery = self

        class ContextTask(TaskBase):
            abstract = True

            def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                if flask.has_app_context():
                    return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
                else:
                    with _celery.app.app_context():
                        return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.Task = ContextTask

    def init_app(self, app):
        self.app = app
        self.config_from_object(app.config)


mail = Mail()
db = SQLAlchemy()
settings = BaseConfig()
celery = FlaskCelery()
```

Then in my `app_settings.py`, I created this app:

```
app = Flask('app', instance_relative_config=True)
```

And configured celery:

```
celery.init_app(app)
```

I ran the flask project with `python manage.py run`:

```
app.run(
        debug=settings.get('DEBUG', False),
        host=settings.get('HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        port=settings.get('PORT', 5000)
    )
```

And ran celery:

```
celery -A manage.celery worker --beat -l debug
```

Celery log looks good:

```
[tasks]
  . app.api.tasks.spin_file
  . app.main.tasks.send_async_email
  . celery.backend_cleanup
  . celery.chain
  ...
```

Then in `views.py`, I call this task:

```
send_async_email.delay(*args, **kwargs)
```

But all tasks are being ignored by Celery. Nothing happens, no errors, no warnings. Nothing.  What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: When I start celery with this command: `celery -A manage.celery worker --beat -l debug`

I get the following warning:

```
[2015-09-21 10:04:32,220: WARNING/MainProcess] /home/.virtualenvs/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/control.py:36: DuplicateNodenameWarning: Received multiple replies from node name: 'name'.
Please make sure you give each node a unique nodename using the `-n` option.
  pluralize(len(dupes), 'name'), ', '.join(sorted(dupes)),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure that this will help you but I am using this code on many of my  projects when ever I need celery:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify as jsn
from celery import Celery
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.update(dict(
    SECRET_KEY='blabla'
    )
)
# Celery configuration
app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'] = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'] = 'database'
app.config['CELERY_RESULT_DBURI'] = 'sqlite:///temp.db'
app.config['CELERY_TRACK_STARTED'] = True
app.config['CELERY_SEND_EVENTS'] = True

# Initialize Celery
celery = Celery(app.name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
celery.conf.update(app.config)

@celery.task
def do_something(data):

    from celery import current_task
    import os
    import subprocess
    with app.app_context():
        #run some bash script with some params in my case
```

And then I am running celery with supervisor via:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /project/location && . venv/bin/activate && celery worker -A appname.celery --loglevel=info --purge #appname is my main flask file
```

And of course in my route i have somthing like

```
@app.route('/someroute', methods=["POST"])
def someroute():
    result = do_something.delay(data)
    print result.id
```

Comment: Man , nothing works on my side, tried to follow your approach. Celery worker and heartbeat runs , but nothing is stored in the database

Comment: When I use the example above it works fine. However, if I run this in my own code, I require redis (ImportError: Missing redis library (pip install redis)). Why does this occur?