# Using a Celery worker to interact with a SQLAlchemy DB, including knowing the user from the request

Tags: python, flask, celery, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-httpauth

I have done plenty of research on this, including trying answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12044776/how-to-use-flask-sqlalchemy-in-a-celery-task/14146403). It appears Celery has no access to my Flask app's context.

I know fully well my celery object, what will decorate my tasks, must have access to my Flask app's context. And I do believe it should, as I followed [this](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/celery/) guide to create my celery object. I am unsure if the confusion lies somewhere in the fact that I am using Flask-HTTPAuth.

Here is some of what I have.

```
def make_celery(app):
    celery = Celery(app.import_name, backend=app.config["CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND"], broker=app.config["CELERY_BROKER_URL"])
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    TaskBase = celery.Task
    class ContextTask(TaskBase):
        abstract = True
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery

app = Flask(__name__)
auth = HTTPBasicAuth()
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///flask_app.db"
app.config["CELERY_BROKER_URL"] = "redis://localhost:6379"
app.config["CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND"] = "redis://localhost:6379"
celery = make_celery(app)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

@celery.task(bind=True, name="flask_app.item_loop")
def loop(self):
    items = g.user.items
    for item in items:
        print(item)
```

Running this task using Flask is a no-go, though. I try to start this function by hitting the server (while authorized!).

```
@app.route("/item_loop")
@auth.login_required
def item_loop():
    result = loop.delay()
    return "It's running."
```

But the Celery worker tells me the task `raised unexpected: AttributeError("'_AppCtxGlobals' object has no attribute 'user'",)`, which I believe would imply, as mentioned, my celery object does not have the app context, even though I used the recommended factory pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the recoomendations in Dave and Greg's answers are valid, what they miss to highlight is the misunderstanding that you have regarding the use of an application context in a Celery task.

You have a Flask application, in which you are using Flask-HTTPAuth. You probably have a `verify_password` handler that sets `g.user` to the authenticated user. This means that while you are handling a request you can access the user as `g.user`. This is all good.

You also have one or more Celery workers, which are separate processes that have no direct connection to the Flask server. The only communication between the Flask server and the Celery worker processes happens over the message broker that you are using (typically Redis or RabbitMQ).

Depending on your needs, the Celery workers may need to have access to the Flask application. This is very common when using Flask extensions that store their configuration in the `app.config` dictionary. Two common extensions that require this are Flask-SQLAlchemy and Flask-Mail. Without access to `app.config`, the Celery task would have no way to open a connection to the database or to send an email, since it would not know the details of the database and/or email server.

To give the Celery workers access to the configuration, the accepted practice is to create duplicate Flask applications in each worker. These are secondary applications that are in no way connected to the actual application object used by the main Flask server. Their only purpose is to hold a copy of the original `app.config` dictionary that can be accessed by your task or by any Flask extensions your task is using.

So it is invalid to expect that a `g.user` set in the Flask server will be accessible also as `g.user` in the Celery task, simply because these are different `g` objects, from different application instances.

If you need to use the authenticated user in the Celery task, what you should do is pass the `user_id` (usually `g.user.id`) as an argument to your task. Then in your task, you can load the user from the database using this `id`. Hope this helps!

Comment: I do think I follow. Loading the user in the task makes perfect sense to me and will work, I have confirmed. Actually writing back to the database seems to be the problem. I am sorry I just cannot quite grasp this. Is that where the duplicate Flask app thing you mentioned comes in?

Comment: If you create a secondary app as I indicated in the answer, you should have no problem reading or writing from the database. If you get a specific error, then you need to expand on that in your question.

Comment: While I am not sure what you mean by create a secondary app, I guess I did it, because I got it working, just really studying the pattern provided. Thanks.

Comment: All I mean by "secondary" is that it isn't the Flask instance that is running the server.

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve the user from within a task execution, you can try passing the User object (if celery can pickle it), or pass along enough information that the task can retrieve the User object (e.g. the User's id). In this latter case, your task would look something like

```
@celery.task(bind=True, name="flask_app.item_loop")
def loop(self, user_id):
    user = User.query.get(user_id)
    items = user.items
    for item in items:
        print(item)
```

and you'd kick it off (assuming you're using flask_login) via

```
result = loop.delay(current_user.id)
```

Comment: Hi, this makes sense and works, but how would I be able to write back to the SQLAlchemy DB? `db.session.commit()` will not work: `name 'db' is not defined`.

Comment: Then you'll need a db that has the same database settings that the Flask app has. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12044776/how-to-use-flask-sqlalchemy-in-a-celery-task for one approach.

Answer (score 2):

As noted by @Dave W. Smith, rather than relying on `g` for retrieving the user, passing the user info as an argument to the Celery task might be a better approach. According to [Flask documentation on app context](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/appcontext/?highlight=app%20context#storing-data), the lifetime of `g` is a request. Since the Celery task is executed asynchronously, it would be executed within a different app context than the one in the request where you defined the user.